# 'Are they something' and 'they are something'

Tags: grammaticality

Which of these sentences is correct?

Are they apples or they are bananas?

Are they apples or are they bananas?

Comment: The second one. Subject-Auxiliary Inversion is obligatory in every question, even if they are conjoined.

Answer (score 2):

When asking a question in English, the verb gets placed before the subject. So, "are they" begins a question, whereas "they are" begins a statement (declarative).

The second option is correct, but it could even be simplified to

> Are they apples or bananas?

without any loss of meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The second. You maintain the same structure in both parts.